# Where is the Programmers site?

Tags: support, software-engineering-se

I remember it was before, but now I can't find it anymore.

Was it deleted? Or replaced by [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It was renamed. programmers.SE is now softwareeningeering.SE

Comment: The cheese only moved, not eaten. :)

Comment: typing programmers.stackexchange.com should take you to the renamed site.

Comment: @ChrisF yes, but if you'll browse the sites list or existing accounts of users, you won't see "programmers" anywhere. (apart of Stack Overflow and Computer Graphics, which have the word "programmers" in their description.)

Comment: good to know...